# ActionCreator Dispatch not Rerendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, jsx

I have a simple drop-down menu for selecting a language, attached to a card that fires off an action `languageSelected()` onClick that should, in turn, re-render the component with the updated language.

The action is definitely firing onClick and I can see the state "change" with redux devtools.
[image]

However, the container component is not rerendering. Still new to Redux so I'm sure it's something silly I'm overlooking.

**container/question**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { languageSelected } from '../../actions/language';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { LANGUAGE_ENGLISH } from '../../actions/actionsTypes';
import { LANGUAGE_SPANISH } from '../../actions/actionsTypes';
import { LANGUAGE_CHINESE } from '../../actions/actionsTypes';
import '../../styles/Main.css';


class Question extends Component {
 render() {
  const {question, language, languageSelected} = this.props;
  let selectedQuestion = language;
  switch (selectedQuestion) {
   case LANGUAGE_SPANISH:
    selectedQuestion = question.q_spanish;
    break;
   case LANGUAGE_CHINESE:
    selectedQuestion = question.q_chinese;
    break;
   default:
    selectedQuestion = question.q_english;
    break;
  }
  return (
   <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="card">
     <div className="card-header">
      <h3 className="pull-left">{question.category}</h3>
      <div className="dropdown">
       <button
        className="btn language-btn dropdown-toggle pull-right"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Language
       </button>
       <div className="dropdown-menu language-drop-down"
         aria-labelledby="dropdownMenubutton">
        <button className="dropdown-item white-link"
          type="button"
          onClick={() => languageSelected(LANGUAGE_ENGLISH)}>
         English
        </button>
        <button className="dropdown-item white-link"
          type="button"
          onClick={() => languageSelected(LANGUAGE_SPANISH)}>
         Spanish
        </button>
        <button className="dropdown-item white-link"
          type="button"
          onClick={() => languageSelected(LANGUAGE_CHINESE)}>
         Chinese
        </button>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div className="card-body">
      <h4>{selectedQuestion}</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  question: state.question.selectedQuestion,
  language: state.language,
  languageSelected: state.language.languageSelected
 };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({languageSelected}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Question);
```

**action/language**

```js
import { LANGUAGE_SELECTED } from './actionsTypes';

export function languageSelected(language){
 return {
  type: LANGUAGE_SELECTED,
  payload: language
 }
}
```

**reducer/language**

```js
import { LANGUAGE_SELECTED } from '../actions/actionsTypes';
import { LANGUAGE_ENGLISH } from '../actions/actionsTypes';
const initialState = {
 selectedLanguage: LANGUAGE_ENGLISH,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
  case LANGUAGE_SELECTED:
   return {...state, selectedLanguage: action.payload};
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

**rootreducer**

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import questions from './questions';
import question from './question';
import language from './language';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 question,
 questions,
 language
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have `languageSelected` in both `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.. it looks like you should be using `selectedLanguage` from the state, but I can't find it in your render code:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        question: state.question.selectedQuestion,
        language: state.language,
        // change from `languageSelected`
        selectedLanguage: state.language.selectedLanguage
    };
}
```

Comment: You just cured my headache. Thank you sir!